# Best technique to avoid function creation in render() method when arguments are involved

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll illustrate my problem by example...

Say I have the following data:

```
const widgets = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob' }
];
```

And it gets passed into a component as a prop, and then gets mapped into elements, like so:

```
class WidgetSelector extends Component {
  onSelected = (widget) => {
    console.log('Selected widget: ', widget);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {
           this.props.widgets.map((widget, i) => 
            <button key={i} onClick={() => this.onSelected(widget)}>
              {widget.name}
            </button>
           )
         }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It appears to be okay on the surface area, but it's currently breaking [performance optimisation guidelines](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#.u9tjp2twz) in the fact that a new function instances are being created on every `render()` (see `onClick={() => onSelected(widget)}`).  Therefore this destroys the "pure" update nature of the child component and child rendering is forced on every parent render call even though there may not have been any actual changes to the child.

The article I linked to refers to an early binding mechanism within the constructor, but my case differs in the fact that I need to pass arguments based on the props.

What is the recommended pattern to avoid this type of scenario?

Should I for example create an array of functions in the constructor of my component and then reference the functions by index? Like so:

```
class WidgetSelector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.widgetSelectors = props.widgets.map(
      widget => () => this.onSelected(widget)
    );
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {
           this.props.widgets.map((widget, i) => 
            <button key={i} onClick={this.widgetSelectors[i]}>
              {widget.name}
            </button>
           )
         }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

That works, but is it the most elegant solution to this problem?

I've created webpackbin implementation of this solution if you wanna play: http://www.webpackbin.com/4ybibSU7b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your data as attributes on the element and reference it that way:

```
var Container = React.createClass({
  data: ['foo', 'bar'],
  handleClick: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-item'))
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
        {this.data.map(d =>
            <button key={d} data-item={d} onClick={this.handleClick}>{d}</button>)}
    </div>;
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50qcxsru/1/)

Comment: Nice! This seems much cleaner!  I shall try this out.

Answer (score 1):

The article you cited points a fix to it by early binding

```
class WidgetSelector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelected = this.onSelected.bind(this);
  }
  onSelected(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.props.widgets.map((widget, i) => 
          <button key={i} onClick={this.onSelected}>
          {widget.name}
          </button>
         )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But with this you cannot pass arguments directly to the function.

Comment: Yep, which is why I pre-bound the arguments in my solution.  Essentially I am creating an array of pre-bound functions with their arguments resolved via closures.  Read my post again. :)
This is kind of the crux of the problem I am trying to solve.  What's the most elegant way of pre-binding when arguments are involved.

Comment: I'll reword my question to make the problem more apparent though. :)

Comment: I do get the point. Note that in my example I used `e.target.innerHTML` to illustrate a concept as a way to identify individual nodes and access needed values.

Comment: Aha, didn't pick that up, sorry.  Yep, that essentially leans towards towards a similar solution as proposed by @JamesBrierleys's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37544009/350933)

Comment: My proposed answer does not really make substantial contribution. It is just a workaround before a better one is figured out to handle it in such common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<button key={i} onClick={onSelected.bind(this, widget)}>
```

Comment: According to the spec:
_"The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called."_.
Therefore this still suffers the same problem as `onClick={() => this.onSelected(widget)}`.